# Setting environment variable for ExecWait child processes

Tags: postgresql, nsis

I am trying to run a SQL file in a NSIS script by using `ExecWait`.
I don't want the password-dialog to pop-up so I am storing the password in the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable (for more info: [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-envars.html)).

If I execute the following command directly in cmd, it works fine:

```
set PGPASSWORD=PasswordText&&psql -U postgres -w -f "Path\To\File.sql" db_name
```

However when I execute the same command in the NSIS script, the `PGPASSWORD` is not set and it fails due to incorrect password:

```
ExecWait 'set PGPASSWORD=$PasswordText&&psql -U postgres -w -f "Path\To\File.sql" db_name'
```

where `PasswordText` is a variable (Var) where I store the password given by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your environment variable directly from the installer with the system plugin, instead of the command sent to `ExecWait`:

```
System::Call 'Kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariableA(t, t) i("PGPASSWORD", "$PasswordText").r0'
ExecWait 'psql -U postgres -w -f "Path\To\File.sql" db_name'
```

See the wiki page concerning [Setting Environment Variables](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Setting_Environment_Variables) for full reference and example of error handling.

Comment: Ha! It works, Thanks! (I thought it wouldn't work for multiple 'ExecWait's , but it does) Just out of curiosity, what was I doing wrong?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but it could be that the command chaining with `&&` does not work the same about modifying the child processes environment when invoking it manually from the console, and when calling it from `ExecWait`

Comment: How can I check the value of PGPASSWORD during runtime? I was trying nsExec::ExecToStack '"$SYSDIR\cmd.exe" echo %PGPASSWORD%' 
 pop $0
 pop $0
 messageBox MB_OK $0, but this doesnt work.

Comment: You can read environment with `ReadEnvStr`, see http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.2.9 for details.

Answer (score 3):

While Seki's answer will work with NSIS v2.46, it is not correct and will not work with Unicode targets. You should never mix the `t` type and A/W function suffix!

Use 
`System::Call 'kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t,t)i("PGPASSWORD", "$PasswordText").r0'` 
or
 `System::Call 'kernel32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "PGPASSWORD", t "$PasswordText")i.r0'`

Comment: Thanks for that point. Do you have some info about about the schedule for the release of unicode NSIS?

Comment: @Seki: Final, no, probably another alpha and and a beta or two first. The current alpha is pretty usable except for the issues discussed in the forum thread...